# How to reduce block time for existing ethreum blockchain network?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, mining, block-interval

I had deployed my private blockchain network back in ***2018-08-12 16:12:48 +0600 (1 year, 167 days ago)***. Since then it is working. At that time the block time was 20-30 seconds which was acceptable for our private transaction. But now a days the average block time has increased to 1 min and sometimes it takes 8-10 minutes to mine a  single block which seems crazy  ;(

[image]

**NB: There are 7 running nodes and all them has 8 GB ram. You can check the geth version in the picture.**

Is there any way so that I can reduce the blocktime ? Or can anybody tell me that upgrading the geth version will solve problem?

genesis.json looks like :-

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 17,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "difficulty": "0x100",
    "gasLimit": "0x2100000",
    "alloc": {
        <ignored>
    }
}
```

And the command is:-

> geth --identity "node_name" --networkid 17  --rpc --rpcaddr
>   "" --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir
>   "node02"  --port "30301" --ipcdisable  --nodiscover  --rpcapi
>   "db,eth,net,web3,personal,miner,admin"

Comment: What configuration values are you running on your nodes. Provide at least command line options and config file, best would be to have the genesis file.

Comment: @NicolasMassart can you please check? let me know if you need more details?

Comment: I will have a look tomorrow but I thin I will need you to run some rpc commands. Do you know how?

Comment: yes . no problem . take your time plz

Comment: Looks like you have configured a PoW chain and the mining speed drops as you have more difficult blocks -- do you have many txns in the chain? Ideally, you'd switch to a PoA chain instead since geth supports it natively

Comment: Yeah. I have used PoW. Is there any way to switch to PoA with existing blocks . I think it is not possible as genesis.json should not be changed. In that case, please suggest me some good articles/blogs so that I can deploy a fresh setup of my blockchain. Anyway I really appreciate your suggestions

Comment: One way to make sure this is because difficulty increase is to check the result of the eth_getblockbynumber RPC command https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/json-rpc#eth_getblockbynumber use "latest" as parameter to check the values for the last block. If difficulty is too high it may just be that you reached the ice age point.

Comment: Did you apply the latest Ethereum changes that lead to the hard fork to delay this ice age and by difficulty bomb?

Comment: Looking at your screenshot it seems that you are running 1.8.27 version that is very old and doesn't provide the difficulty bomb delay deployed as a fork in begining of the year and known as Muir glacier. Updating geth to latest 1.9.10 should do some good.

Comment: I have updated my all the geth to  
Geth/v1.9.10-stable-58cf5686/linux-amd64/go1.13.6
 but still no luck